# Find dom elements across multiple templates in meteor

Tags: meteor

It's simple in jquery to search all of the DOM for a specific element, however meteor seems to limit searches (Find) to with a single template. Is there a more meteor way to do this? E.g. Document.find('#element').value

Comment: Just use `$('#element')` instead of `this.find('#element')`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It's more the other way around. I can search across all templates easily with jquery but wanted to know the proper meteor way as jquery might catch me out as the template is reactive?? Any help would he great, there isn't much good noobie resources yet.

Comment: Meteor reactivity only happens when reactive variables (Meteor.user(), Session, cursors, etc.) change. DOM changes themselves cannot trigger reactivity. You may want to rephrase your question to be more specific. I suspect using a session variable would solve your problem.